# best way to do a mail merge for an .NET application?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4

Currently I am developing an MVC application.  I have been given a word template, which I need  to use to create a mail merge.  The data for the merge is in a database, can I create a mail merge document on the fly? has anyone done this before? what tools have you used? any helpful hints?

Basically the process of creating the mail merge will be, a user clicks a button, which in turns gets the template and populates it with the data (there will be a few hundred records returned), when the mail merge has completed, I want to return a single word document that contains all the letters in it.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I faced this problem and unfortunately there are 3 solutions, all terrible in some way:

### OOXML API

Use the Office Open XML API: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124 - and manually walk the Document XML tree to inspect the mail-merge elements, perform the text replacement yourself, then save.

#### Advantages:

- Free

#### Disadvantages

- It took me 6 months of stressing with this approach before giving up
- No built-in API for mail-merge
- Simple merge-field replacement is simple enough, but there are complex-fields spread out over several `<w:run>` elements which are a pain to replace. Bonus: since Word 2010 all new fields are the complex type.
- Only support OOXML files (`.docx`). No support for Word 97-2003 files (`.doc`).

### Aspose Saas (formerly Saaspose) API

#### Advantages:

- Cheap (from $15/month)
- Works with all Word file formats
- Simple, gets the job done

#### Disadvantages

- If you want to do anything more than a simple field replacement (i.e. repeating regions, "if ... then ..." show/hide logic, use a complex data structure as a data source) then you're SOL.
- It's a web-service, so you always need a connection from your server to theirs
- Their ".NET SDK" is horribly designed (e.g. full of instance methods that should be static). I wrote my own replacement, I probably should upload it at some point.
- Their documentation isn't the best either, though this might have improved lately, but good luck trying to navigate it.

### Aspose Words

#### Advantages

- It just works
- Very powerful, perform any kind of merge and field manipulation, including using your own complex data sources
- Great support service from the developers

#### Disadvantages

- Expensive. Starts from $999 USD for a single-user/single-site license. If you're developing a SaaS application then you need the $3000 USD license.

Comment: Thanks for that, at the moment they are using a word template.  But it doesn't have to be a word template, all they need at the end of the day is to print some docuemnts.. are there pdf templates etc? any other alternatives?

Comment: Take a look at SQL Server Reporting Services, or just rendering a printable HTML report using ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost: don't use interop, because it doesn't work well in server environment (see Microsoft's KB 257757).

I have good experience with [Docentric Toolkit](http://www.docentric.com/). I have been using it for three years now. So here are its pros and cons:

Pros:

- plain simple Word Add-in for template generation
- OpenXML based, server side friendly
- support for images, data-bound graphs, tables
- conditional elements in templates
- support for placeholders in headers and footers
- very fast report generation

Cons:

- not free
- somewhat lesser support for PDF output

Answer (score 0):

Have you tryed NTemplates? Not exactly for Word documents but if you don't mind using RTF, it might be the solution. Download full source code and examples for free from ntemplates.codeplex.com